# How can you start a browser at a specific URL using the selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

So if I do the following:

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome() # this results in the browser displaying the about page
 driver.get("http://somesite.com/")  # now the browser goes to the URL
```

Then if I check the history length via the javascript console in the browser I get a value of 2.
I need to simulate the situation where a new tab or window is opened with the URL and thus a history length of 1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set some specific flags to pass to your WebDriver when you initialize it.  You can see examples [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) (for Chrome), and there is also a link to a full list of switches.  Here is how to set the homepage for ChromeDriver in java:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches",
        Arrays.asList("--homepage=http://somesite.com/"));
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet.. but if this is the case, then i'd prefer this method

Answer (score 1):

options.AddArgument("--homepage \"url\"");
like this， set null homepage：
options.AddArgument("--homepage \"data:,\"");

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 3 possible options here. (1 may not be)

#### Option 1:

Design your own `get` method which will execute javascript. something like,
`window.location.replace("http://somesite.com/")` so it will not be logged into history.

#### Option 2:

In your validations, just make sure you validate `n-1` to "pretend" it wasn't there.

#### Option 3: (not sure of the possibility of this)

Using the [JavascriptExecutor](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html), find out a way that you can modify the `history` object and just take that initial `about:blank` history entry out.